# Convert multiple dates to Unix time in PHP

Tags: php, unix, time, mktime

Hi I have a few dates coming in random formats:

```
    Wed, 16 Mar 2011 15:27:48 +0000
```

or

```
2011-03-16T17:42:05+0000
```

and I need to be able to convert them into Unix time in PHP. I assume I need to use mktime() , ,but how do I format my mktime ? I'm having trouble understanding the examples in the manual :/

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strtotime()` can work, but if the dates you're passing in are ambiguous (what is 01/02/03? Feb 1st, '03? Mar 2 '01?) it'll turn around and chew you a new one.

Safest option is to use [`date_create_from_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php), which lets you specify an explicit format for the input.

Comment: At least the two example formats work fine with `strtotime` and remove the need to try out multiple *possible* formats if you don't know in what format the date is..

Answer (score 1):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)